# SNS getEndpointAttributes Returns Old Data After EventEndpointUpdated Event

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js

When attaching a topic to a SNS application's "Endpoint updated" configurable topic I'm experiencing some unexpected behavior. Per AWS's documentation on [SNS Application Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/application-event-notifications.html), I should receive an event on my configured topic when a platform endpoint has been updated to disabled or it's token changed.

In my case I have a lambda function subscribed to this topic that then retrieves the platform endpoint's attributes via a call to AWS's javascript sdk `SNS.getEndpointAttributes` so that I can check what attribute have changed to either delete the endpoint or update the associated token in my persistent storage. This call however is returning the endpoints as `Enabled = true` which then prevents me from taking the corrective actions. However if I look in the AWS SNS console I can see the endpoint has been disabled as `Enabled = false`.

Have others experienced similar inconsistencies and if so what's the best practice to get around them? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also facing the similar problem when amazon notified me sns application events via http. To work around this problem i actually delayed the execution of code that sync these endpoint updates with my database. To achieve this i scheduled a job for my background queue worker and delayed its execution after 30 seconds from the time amazon notified via http. I don't know whether it is a best practice or not but it is working in my scenario.

Comment: I do something similar. I sleep for 60s in my lambda function that is invoked by the "Endpoint updated" event.